# Set parameters on subclass without initing it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, subclass

I have an `UIImageView` subclass and am grabbing the image from a URL.

To initialize the class you have to use `initWithFrame: andURL:`

However, I have other options that I would like to be able to set without having to create 10 different custom `init` methods.  In the subclass, there are about 5 other variables, and I would not like to create unnecessary `init`s if I don't need to.  Sorry if this is hard to follow - see this example:

```
CustomImageView *imageView = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andURL:url];
[imageView setSize:x];
[imageView setColor:y];
//I want the user to be able to set other variables to add parameters to the URL,
// but I don't want to have initWithFrame: andURL: andSize: or initWithFrame: andURL:
// andSize: andColor:
```

Is there a way to load the image with these parameters without using adding a `(void)loadImage` to the subclass?  Sorry again if this is confusing, any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does `loadImage` do?

Comment: @BlackRider loadImage does nothing - I was seeing if I could set variables before loading the URL.

Comment: Use the standard init method instead of your initWithFrame: andURL:.  and then passing all values over later to the properties on subclass.  When you ready to display the image, call the loadImage.  (You will need to tell it to display image somehow.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a property in your image view subclass:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *imageUrl;`

You can now set the URL at any time with:

`[imageView setImageUrl:url];`

Comment: Should I then remove `initWithFrame: andURL:`?

Comment: @1789040: If the variable is required to initialize the class, you should obviously have it on an initializer. If not, then it's a matter of personal preference. A good rule of thumb is, what options would someone most likely want to set when creating an instance? That way you can condense the common case of `init; foo=; bar=;` into the more concise `initWithFoo:Bar:`.

Comment: Well you will need to initialize the `UIImageView` and sets it's frame. But you can remove your custom initializer and just set the URL on re-use.